# show progress bar until video loads IOS7

Tags: ios, video, progress-bar

Hi in my application I'm playing the video using URL. I'm passing the video URL form my server now the problem its taking to much time to play the video. So i want to show progress bar until its load the video .

So i have used the MBProgressHUD for progress bar its showing the progress bar but the video is not playing please tell where I'm doing wrong.

My code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString * currentVideo = [videoarray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSString *strurl=[self urlencode:currentVideo];
     NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strurl];
     NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSURLConnection *con=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
  if (con) {

      datas=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

  }
     spinner =  [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

     spinner.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

     [spinner setLabelText:@"Loading file....."];

     [spinner setLabelFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

     [spinner show:YES];

 }


-(NSString *)urlencode:(NSString *)str
 {
      NSString *encodeString=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
      return encodeString;
 }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     NSLog(@"%lld",[response expectedContentLength]);

     self.length = [response expectedContentLength];
 }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1{
[datas appendData:data1];

    float progress =  (float)[datas length]/(float)self.length;
    NSLog(@"%f",progress);

   float check=progress*100;
   if (check==100) {
      [spinner hide:YES];

      [spinner removeFromSuperViewOnHide];

  }

}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

      NSData *data = datas;
      NSLog(@"%@",data);
      NSString* myurl;
      myurl = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:datas encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",myurl);

   _movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:myurl]];
  [[_movieplayer view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

  [self.view addSubview: [_movieplayer view]];
  [_movieplayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
  [_movieplayer prepareToPlay];
  [_movieplayer play];


}
```

I have used the above code its not playing the video please tell where I'm doing wrong in the above code how to achieve this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1.create new view control

2.pass your videoarray1 value to nextvieww control i mean your video url

3.add following code nextview control

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    self.indicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.indicator];
    [self.indicator startAnimating];

    _movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[self urlencode:self.strPlayUrl]]];
    [[_movieplayer view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview: [_movieplayer view]];
    [_movieplayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [_movieplayer prepareToPlay];

    //this is the line we need to do
    [self.view insertSubview:self.movieplayer.view belowSubview:self.indicator];
    [self.movieplayer play];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"VIEW DID LOAD");
    // Register to receive a notification that the movie is now in memory and ready to play
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieLoadStateDidChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

}

-(void)movieLoadStateDidChange:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"STATE CHANGED");
    if(MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK ) {
        NSLog(@"State is Playable OK");
        NSLog(@"Enough data has been buffered for playback to continue uninterrupted..");
         self.indicator.hidden = YES;
        [ self.indicator stopAnimating];
    }

}


-(NSString *)urlencode:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *encodeString=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return encodeString;
}
```